# Issue box-sizing:border-box

Tags: css

I'm trying to add the boxes side by side and when I try like below, nothing happened. 
Can you help me in this case?

```
.block{

box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried so far? Showing at least minimal effort put into solving an issue is required on StackOverflow.

Comment: Check all information.

Comment: HTML        <div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Pela luz dos olhos teus               
       </p>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
         <p>Pela luz dos olhos teus
         </p>
                </div>

Comment: .block{ float:left;
                widows: 33.33%; 
                padding:10px;
                border:1px solid #ccc;
                box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Pela luz dos olhos teus </p>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Pela luz dos olhos teus </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I use Visual Studio Code, and I don't know if there is any problem with my editor. Is it possible?

Comment: @LeandroAlbuquerque What do you want exactly. Show any image or demo then I will be able to help you.  Anyway there is no issue of editor.

Comment: I'd like to put the class="block" side by side, then it becomes two boxes.

Comment: @LeandroAlbuquerque You better design what you want in copy and provide image of that.